# How to handle errors to dispatch a POST in redux

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Hi I am new to Redux and looking how to handle errors to dispatch a POST using axios with thunk.  I am trying to catch any error coming from the extra reducers. I am using a console.log for error temporarily. Any feedback will be great! Here is a snip of my code:

```
export const postInfo = createAsyncThunk(
  'info/postInfo'
  async (infoObject: InfoRequest) => {
    const response = await axios.post(`${url}/info`, infoObject);
    return response.data;
  }
);
...
extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder
    ....
    .addCase(postInfo.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.request.status = 'failed';
      state.request.error = action.error.message;
    })
}
...
const sendInfoRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const infoObjRequest: InfoRequest = {
      userId: 8,
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Smith'
    };
    await dispatch(postInfo(infoObjRequest));
  } catch (err) {
       // TODO: how to use error handling for rejected?      
       console.log('rejected for post /info', err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Take a look at [Checking Errors After Dispatching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#checking-errors-after-dispatching)

Comment: @slideshowp2 yes I have looked at that page as well, just wondering if I can do it catch block so its not that messy since the extra reducer already calls an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by [unwrapping-result-actions](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions).

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { configureStore, createAsyncThunk, createSlice, unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const postInfo = createAsyncThunk('info/postInfo', async () => {
  throw new Error('get post info fails');
});
const postInfoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'postInfo',
  initialState: {
    request: { status: 'idle', error: '' },
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(postInfo.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.request.status = 'failed';
      state.request.error = action.error.message as string;
    });
  },
});

const store = configureStore({ reducer: postInfoSlice.reducer });

const sendInfoRequest = async () => {
  try {
    await store.dispatch(postInfo()).unwrap();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('rejected for post /info', err);
  }
};

sendInfoRequest();
```

Execution result:

```sh
rejected for post /info {
  name: 'Error',
  message: 'get post info fails',
  stack: 'Error: get post info fails\n' +
    '    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/71070359/index.ts:4:9\n' +
    '    at step (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/71070359/index.ts:33:23)\n' +
    '    at Object.next (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/71070359/index.ts:14:53)\n' +
    '    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/71070359/index.ts:8:71\n' +
    '    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at __awaiter (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/71070359/index.ts:4:12)\n' +
    '    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/71070359/index.ts:3:59\n' +
    '    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.cjs.development.js:1172:57\n' +
    '    at step (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.cjs.development.js:38:23)\n' +
    '    at Object.next (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/redux-examples/packages/redux-toolkit-example/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.cjs.development.js:19:53)'
}
```

Or, return a rejected value use `thunkAPI.rejectWithValue()` instead of throw error in thunk.

```
export const postInfo = createAsyncThunk('info/postInfo', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
  // throw new Error('get post info fails');
  return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ code: 2000, message: 'parameter invalid' });
});
```

Execution result:

```sh
rejected for post /info { code: 2000, message: 'parameter invalid' }
```

Comment: slideshowp2, is been some time but wanted to make a change how to use unwrap instead of using the `console.log('rejected for post /info', err);` for cleaning all those console.log, I like how unwrap give you an output when it is fullfiled, but when it fails the error throw in the console.log are not clear, too.  let me know